# In renal physiology, increased ABP/decreased COP cause natriuresis, but AngII efferent arteriole dilation/GFR increase cause antinatriuresis?

Tags: renal

Per my understanding:

- Increased ABP (arterial blood pressure) leads to increased GFR. This then causes pressure natriuresis. Moreover, peritubular capillary pressure also increases, increasing renal interstitial hydrostatic pressure (RIHP) and therefore decreasing fluid reabsorption and causing natriuresis.
- Decreased COP (colloid osmotic pressure) in the GFR leads to natriuresis. Moreover it would increase RIHP and therefore act in a similar manner to ABP.
- However, constriction of the efferent arterioles in the kidneys via angiotensin 2 conversely decreases natriuresis. It's not been explained in my course exactly why this is, but some coursemates and I suspect that as GFR increases in relation to flow through the peritubular capillaries, the colloid osmotic pressure in the capillaries builds up, causing increased fluid reabsorption from the lumen through the starling forces and therefore preventing natriuresis.

I'm a bit confused about why the effects are opposite. Moreover, what's the exact mechanism by which decreased COP/ABP causes natriuresis?

A theory I had was that increased ABP/decreased COP have effects in both the tubule and the peritubular capillaries. E.g. pressure would increase in both the tubule and peritubular capillaries, and therefore 'balance' in some way (e.g. there wouldn't be net fluid reabsorption and therefore no Na+ reabsorption by solvent drag). Moreover, AngII-mediated efferent arteriole constriction would cause increase in GFR whereas fluid flow to peritubular capillaries decrease. This would then potentially cause the antinatriuretic effect.